# How to use dotnet tool during Travis-CI build?

Tags: .net-core, travis-ci, dotnet-tool

I'm trying to use [dotnet-warp](https://github.com/Hubert-Rybak/dotnet-warp) as a global tool in my .NET Core Travis-CI build, because I like the idea of a single executable so much better than a folder full of 75ish files.

I can successfully add the tool and verify there's a tools/dotnet folder in the $PATH...

But the log indicates that because .NET Core has been added recently, I'll need to restart or logout before I can actually use the tool.

Is anyone aware of a way to make this work in the Travis-CI environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ran into the same issue, using the info from the [Travis CI Installing Dependencies](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/installing-dependencies/) page and [this](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/9273#issuecomment-388570496) comment on an issue about it, adding the following following to to my .travis.yml solved the problem:

```
before_script:
  - export PATH=$PATH:/home/travis/.dotnet/tools
```

My build log:

```
$ export PATH=$PATH:/home/travis/.dotnet/tools

$ dotnet tool install -g dotnet-warp
You can invoke the tool using the following command: dotnet-warp
Tool 'dotnet-warp' (version '1.0.9') was successfully installed.
The command "dotnet tool install -g dotnet-warp" exited with 0.

$ cd ./src/[my project]/
The command "cd ./src/[my project]/" exited with 0.

$ dotnet-warp
Running Publish...
Running Pack...
Saved binary to "[my project]"
The command "dotnet-warp" exited with 0.
```

Comment: I had seen both of those links and hadn't quite been able to put them together in a way that worked. This worked like a charm--thank you!!